# How can I run a Haskell file using window's powershell?

Tags: powershell, haskell

I downloaded `chocolatey` and am able to load up `ghci` and get prelude on `powershell`.
I then cd into the directory where I have a haskell file I want to run, then I type `ghci` and then type:

```
load haskellprogram.hs
```

but then I get an error about it not being in scope.
Is this not how you run a Haskell program?

Comment: This means there is a problem with the file: that it calls a function/uses a constant/... that was not defined/imported.

Comment: What is the exact error message?  It probably isn't relevant to powershell.  Haskell is particularly awkward for beginners.  You might have to import some other module for example.

Answer (score 0):

The GHCi command to load a file is `:load`, not `load`. You should write:

```
:load haskellprogram.hs
```

The command can also be abbreviated `:l`. You can find more information about the available commands in GHCi by entering `:help`. Also note that the prompt shows the modules you have imported; `Prelude` is just the name of the standard library module that gets imported by default. You can change the prompt with:

```
:set prompt "> "
:set prompt-cont "| "
```

(Where `prompt-cont` is the prompt for multi-line input, using the commands `:{` and `:}` or the multi-line input mode enabled by `:set +m`.)

When you entered `load haskellprogram.hs`, it was interpreted as a Haskell expression: `(load haskellprogram) . hs`, which tries to use the `(.)` composition operator and three variables `load`, `haskellprogram`, and `hs` that are not defined.